# Extract subdomain from url using regex

Tags: asp.net, regex, subdomain

I've searched through all of the related topics here but none seems to answer my specific need. Here is the problem: Given a URL (sans protocol), I want to extract the subdomain portion, excluding www. The domain portion is always the same so I don't need to support all TLDs. Examples:

```
www.subdomain.domain.com should match subdomain
www.domain.com should match nothing
domain.com should match nothing
```

This is one of the many iterations I have tried:

```
[^(www\.)]\w+[^(\.domain\.com)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square brackets indicate character class and will remove all the order of otherwise special meaning of most characters.

You can try something like this instead:

```
((?:[^.](?<!www))+)\.domain\.com
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/jX8dK8)

To return what you're looking for instead of retrieving it through submatches:

```
((?:[^.](?<!www))+)(?=\.domain\.com)
```

[regexp101 revised](http://www.regex101.com/r/hZ4cL4)

Comment: Thanks Jerry, but that still matches the "domain.com" portion of "subdomain.domain.com". I should have specified "match" instead of "return" in my original post - I will edit it right now.

Comment: @fatman45 Oh sure, just turn the second part into a positive lookahead. I updated my answer :)